# Как правильно дампить процесс в JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

Вообщем имею запущенный main.jar файл, нужно сдампить его в файл, есть команда:

```
jmap -F -dump <file> <pid>
```

но она работает не корректно (выводит ошибку прикрепления). 
Как правильно вызвать эту команду ?

Comment: Можно увидеть конкретно ту команду, которую вы запускаете и полный текст ошибки?

Comment: jmap -dump:format=b,file=cheap.bin pid
http://screenshot.ru/8a86851f7a30ffc49083bf650f89a84e.png

Comment: Похоже что main.jar запущен под JVM версии 1.5 или ниже. Попробуйте использовать для запуска main.jar JVM версии 1.6 и выше.

Comment: Немного не по сути вопроса. Для мониторинга JVM существуют удобные графические инструменты [Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) (начиная с JDK 6u7) и [Java Mission Control](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaseproducts/mission-control/java-mission-control-1998576.html) (начиная с JDK 7u40)

Comment: @Ilya main.jar был запущен под JRE v8 ну а JDK у меня v7 u67
Когда-то слышал на одном форуме что "на Java 6 дампить вообще легко" так ли это ?

Answer (score 3):

Многие тулы из jdk с флагом -F используют serviceability агента, без одной хитрой проперти он упадёт, если версии jvm (вплоть до версий билда) не будут совпадать. Имеется в виду версии jvm целевого процесса и которая запускает агента. Попробуйте без этого флага, в таком случае будет использован dynamic attach api